# How to response different data that was inserted by create method (ModelViewSet)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm implementing a stock shoes manager with REST architecture using Django + Django rest.

Im using a custom Router inherited from DefaultRouter to serve my endpoints.

In the `/resources/id` endpoint Ive added one more verb, `POST` that is called  by `custom_create` method.

Here you can see this `custom_create` method:

viewsets.py

```
class ShoeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Shoe.objects.all()
    filter_class = ShoeFilter

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'custom_create':
            return StockPostSerializer
        else:
            return ShoeSerializer

    def custom_create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}

        data['shoe'] = kwargs['pk']
        data['size'] = request.data.get('size')
        data['amount'] = request.data.get('amount')

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

I needed to do this because I have two models, below you can see my 3 Serializers:

serializers.py

```
class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ['size', 'amount']

class ShoeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stock = StockSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Shoe
        fields = ['description', 'provider', 'type', 'cost_price','sale_price','total_amount', 'stock']

class StockPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ['shoe','size', 'amount']
```

The `retrieve` (`GET` verb) method of this endpoint expects data serialized by `ShoeSerializer`, but the `custom_create` method insert data using the `StockPostSerializer`. How can I return a response with a different data that was inserted ?

When I try to insert with this endpoint I recieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdSar.png) error message, but when I refresh the page I realize that the content was inserted (If i use postman instead of de DRF frontend I dont get any error message, works fine).

How can my `custom_create` method Responses correctly ?

You can check my [github](https://github.com/tamercuba/Shoes-Stock-Inventory-Management-System), the names will be a bit different because I translated it here so that it is easier for you to understand.

**PS**: As you may have noticed I am not a native speaker of the English language, so it is very difficult to express myself here but I am trying my best, and learning more and more. If my question contains grammar / concordance errors please correct them but you do not have to refuse me so I'm trying to learn!

Comment: In your **`get_serializer_class()`** method, you are returning `EstoquePostSerializer` and in your question you want `StockPostSerializer`. Can you clarify that?

Comment: My code is in Portuguese, I translated into English so you understand what each variable name is about. I forgot to translate this, thanks for the feedback.Everything is already correct.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, You need to serialize the data using **`StockPostSerializer`** if the view action is **`custom_create`**, otherwise **`ShoeSerializer`**. right?

Comment: apart from that, can you post the error message in english or a screenshot of english version?

Comment: I finally managed to solve this problem, after several days and about 10 issues in that question. I'll post a detailed solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to sort this out, and in a much more elegant way than I had been trying beforehand.

What I need to do is: add new stock instances, for this I had created a new route for POST in the endpoint resources/id.

So I was able to reuse the Default Router, delete the `custom_create` method, and just modified the serializers.py file.
It looks like this:

serializers.py

```
class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ['size', 'amount']

class ShoeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    stock = StockSerializer(many=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.description   = validated_data.get(
            'description', instance.description)
        instance.provider  = validated_data.get(
            'provider', instance.provider)
        instance.type        = validated_data.get('type', instance.type)
        instance.cost_price = validated_data.get(
            'cost_price', instance.cost_price)
        instance.salve_price = validated_data.get(
            'sale_price', instance.sale_price)

        stock      = instance.stock.all()
        stock_data = validated_data.get('stock', [])

        for item_data in stock_data:
            item_id = item_data.get('size', None)
            if item_id is not None:
                item_db            = stock.get(size=item_id)
                item_db.size    = item_data.get('size', item_db.size)
                item_db.amount = item_data.get('amount',item_db.amount)
                item_db.save()
            else:
                Estoque.objects.create(
                    shoe = instance,
                    size    = item_data['size'],
                    amount = item_data['amount']
                )
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Shoe
        fields = ['_id','description', 'provider', 'type', 'cost_price','sale_price','total_amount', 'stock']
```

Now, via `PATCH` verb I can add new Stock instances and alter existing stock instances. Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly by looking at your code, in this case specifically, you don't need the `StockPostSerializer`. You can acheive the result you want by changing `StockSerializer` as follows:

```
class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ['shoe', 'size', 'amount']
        extra_kwargs = {'shoe': {'write_only': True}}
```

I greatly apologize if I misunderstood your question.

EDIT:

Forgot to say. Using this serializer you don't need any extra route on your `ModelViewSet`